# SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild fails on successive invocations; unable to clean .sonarqube dir

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Basically, I need to invoke msbuild three times in succession.  Each of the three builds needs to be scanned.  The first one is OK, but the 2nd and 3rd fail because the scanner is unable to clean the .sonarqube directory.
I get "Access to the path 'SonarQube.Common.dll' is denied.
It appears that the .dll is still in use, even though I put a 60 second delay between the builds.

Here is a snippet of the output:

```
C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp>SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:com.carestream.SteveK_Backend /n:SteveK_Backend /v:1.0 /s:C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\src\Backend_Sonar_Properties.xml 
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2
Loading analysis properties from C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\src\Backend_Sonar_Properties.xml
sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
Removing the existing directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube
Creating directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube
12:50:27.707  12:50:27.703  Loading analysis properties from C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\src\Backend_Sonar_Properties.xml
12:50:27.707  12:50:27.707  sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
12:50:27.708  Updating build integration targets...
12:50:27.709  The file SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets is up to date at C:\Users\rocbuilder\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
12:50:27.709  The file SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets is up to date at C:\Users\rocbuilder\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
12:50:27.71  The file SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets is up to date at C:\Users\rocbuilder\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\12.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
12:50:27.711  Installed SonarQube.Integration.targets to C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube\bin\targets
12:50:27.712  Creating config and output folders...
...

C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp>SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end 
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2
Default properties file was found at C:\SonarQube\Scanners\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\SonarQube\Scanners\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
12:52:04.002  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
12:52:04.003  Not running under TeamBuild
12:52:04.004  Analysis base directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube
Build directory: 
Bin directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube\bin
Config directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube\conf
Output directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube\out
Config file: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml

...
:: CAUSE A DELAY BETWEEN 1st and 2nd Scan

C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp>PING localhost -n61  1>NUL 


C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp>SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:com.carestream.SteveK_WebCSharp /n:SteveK_WebCSharp /v:1.0 /s:C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\src\Web_Sonar_Properties.xml 
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2
Loading analysis properties from C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\src\Web_Sonar_Properties.xml
sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
Removing the existing directory: C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube
Failed to create an empty directory 'C:\home\repos\SteveKTemp\.sonarqube'. Please check that there are no open or read-only files in the directory and that you have the necessary read/write permissions.
  Detailed error message: Access to the path 'SonarQube.Common.dll' is denied.
Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in finding a way to get around this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Kirsteen's answer (re: /noderesuse:false) did the trick.
Thanks Kirsteen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there is an additional option they recommend when running multiple builds in succession.

```
pass /nodereuse:false to msbuild
```

See troubleshooting:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild